# Creating contour and then perform pixel analysis (OpenCV)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, pixel, contour

If I have an RGB image and a binary mask (1 channel), and I want to create contours for the RGB image based on the connected pixels of the binary mask. After that I want to compare the pixel values (e.g. check if each pixel in the contours is having a blue value > 150), then how can I implement the above by using OpenCV?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to access just all pixels of your contour or all pixels bounded by that contour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the images are the same size and shape then simply scan over the pixels in the binary image looking for the contours and check the pixel values at the same row/col in the color image

See [Fastest way to extract individual pixel data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963617/opencv-fastest-way-to-extract-individual-pixel-data/8963744#comment11229455_8963744) for details