# C++ equivalent of OpenCV's cvConvertImage

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I'm looking for the C++ equivalent of `cvConvertImage` in OpenCV.

```
cvConvertImage(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, int flags=0)
```

Specifically, I have a `cv::Mat` image with the red and blue channels flipped, and I wish to swap them back. In cvConvertImage you can do this by setting flags to be `CV_CVTIMG_SWAP_RB`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Late answer, but you can use `cv::cvtColor(...)` with option `CV_BGR2RGB` if you want to swap `R` and `B`.

If you want more complex operations `mixchannels` is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

I think [mixChannels()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20mixChannels%28const%20Mat%2a%20src,%20int%20nsrc,%20Mat%2a%20dst,%20int%20ndst,%20const%20int%2a%20fromTo,%20size_t%20npairs%29) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

TO access individual pixels see [Fastest way to extract individual pixel data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963617/opencv-fastest-way-to-extract-individual-pixel-data/8963744#8963744)

Then it's just a matter of swapping the red / blue values

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any method in the C++ interface to do this, but if you don't want to do a manual swap like @Martin suggested, you can still convert `cv::Mat` to `IplImage` and use `cvConvertImage` to do the job for you:

```
// Load image into: cv::Mat mat_img;
...

// Convert cv::Mat to IplImage
IplImage ipl_img = mat_img;

cvConvertImage(&ipl_img , &ipl_img , CV_CVTIMG_SWAP_RB);
```